# GCC, functions, and pointer arguments, warning behaviour

Tags: c, gcc, pointers, arguments, warnings

I've recently updated to a testing distribution, which is now using GCC 4.4.3. Now I've set everything up, I've returned to coding and have built my project and I get one of these horrible messages:

`*** glibc detected *** ./boxyseq: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001d873e8 ***`

I absolutely know what is wrong here, but was rather confused as to when I saw my C code where I call a function which frees a dynamically allocated data structure - I had passed it an incompatible pointer type - a pointer to a completely different data structure.

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'data_A_free' from incompatible pointer type
note: expected 'struct data_A *' but argument is of type 'struct data_B *'
```

I'm confused because I'm sure this would have been an error before and compilation would never have completed. Is this not just going to make life more difficult for C programmers?

Can I change it back to an error without making a whole bunch of other warnings errors too?

Or am I loosing the plot and it's always been a warning?

Comment: I'll delete this question if it's always been a warning!

Comment: if you know how to make this in particular an error, please post.  It's covered by -pedantic-errors, but that's broader.

Comment: @Matthew so it has always been a warning? If I find out I'll post, but a quick search through http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html didn't reveal anything.

Comment: No, I don't know about that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always been a warning.  C allows you to implicitly cast any pointer to any other pointer, although any half-decent compiler will warn you.

It's an error in C++, though.  Perhaps that's what you were thinking of?

In GCC, you can turn a warning into an error using [-Werror=](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), but I don't see an option for this particular warning.  You could just use -Werror to turn *all* warnings into errors, but that might do more than you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely one of the things that the [clang analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) would catch, and therefore you can make it an error building with clang.

Comment: You can make it an error with gcc too (`-pedantic-errors`).  The question is can you avoid making a bunch of other warnings errors.

Comment: Eurrgghh, just read the wikipedia page about it: "Its goal is to offer a replacement to the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC). Development is sponsored by Apple..." no thanks.